# Is $\{n\pmod \pi: n \in \Bbb N\}$ dense in $[0,\pi]$?

Tags: real-analysis

Is $\{n\pmod\pi: n\in\Bbb N\}$ dense in $[0,\pi]$ ? Is there a proof or well known theorem for this result?

My intuition would say that it is dense.

Comment: By $n \mod \pi$, do you mean $\frac{n}{\pi} - floor(\frac{n}{\pi})$?

Comment: Yes, n divided by pi and we take the remainder as the result.

Comment: Do you know whether $\bigl\{n\cdot \frac{1}{\pi} \bmod 1 : n \in \mathbb{N}\bigr\}$ is dense in $[0,1]$?

Comment: Not only for $\pi$, but for any irrational number. (I'm trying to remember the proof).

Comment: @ajotatxe I would be greatly interested in it

Comment: @DanielFischer I don't know this, I was wondering about this as part of another question involving the limit of $sin(n)$

Comment: ZirconCode, a [remotely related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2373322/721644).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $\{\cdot\}$ be the *fractional part*. $\Bbb N$ is the set of *positive* integers. 
As a preliminary property, have in mind that if $x$ is real and $m,n$ are integers, then $\{m\{nx\}\}=\{mnx\}$.

Let $x$ be an irrational number. Then $\{nx\}\neq 0$ for every $n\in\Bbb N$. For the moment, let's see the following:

> For every $\epsilon>0$, there exists some $n\in\Bbb N$ such that
>   $\{nx\}<\epsilon$.

Suppose not. Then $\delta=\inf\big\{\{nx\}:n\in\Bbb N\big\}$ is not $0$. Obviously, $\delta<1$. Let $m$ be the natural such that $\delta m\ge 1$ and $\delta(m-1)<1$. We have then $1\le m\delta<1+\delta$.

Take any $0<\epsilon<1+\delta-m\delta$. There exists some $k\in\Bbb N$ such that $0<\{kx\}-\delta<\epsilon/m$, so 
$$1\le\delta m<m\{kx\}<m\delta+\epsilon<1+\delta<2$$
Therefore
$$0<\{kmx\}<m\delta+\epsilon-1<\delta,$$
a contradiction.

Now the proof:

> For every interval $(a,b)\subset[0,1]$, there is some $n$ such that $\{nx\}\in(a,b)$. That is, $\big\{\{nx\}:n\in\Bbb N\big\}$ is dense in $[0,1]$.

We know that there is $m\in\Bbb N$ such that $0<\{mx\}<b-a<1$. Now take the minimal integer $k$ such that $k\{mx\}>a$. Then $a<\{kmx\}<b$.

Comment: This is great, thanks!

Comment: [A bit related answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3333656/721644).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** By the [Dirichlet Approximation Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem) $\frac{n}{\pi} \pmod{1}$ is dense in $[0,1)$.

You can easily show that this is equivalent to your statement.

Comment: Thank you! Just to make sure, $\pi$ in this case could be any irrational number without any other requirement?

Comment: @ZirconCode Yes, the claim and proof are the same for any irrational number.