# Is the set of periodic functions a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$? Explain.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, periodic-functions

A function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is called periodic if there exists a positive number $p$ such that $f(x) = f(x + p)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Is the set of periodic functions from $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$? Explain.

attempt: Suppose S be the set of periodic functions.
Then we must show that $S$ is a subspace or not. We must check it's not empty, and that it's closed under addition and scalar  multiplication.
Let $f,g \in S$. Then $f,g$ are periodic. So their sum is also.
Thus, $(f + g)(x+ p) = f(x + p) + g(x + p) = f(x) + g(x) = (f + g)(x)$.
So it's closed under addition.
I am confused , I don't really understand. Can someone please help ? Thank you.

Comment: You are fine, now all you must show is that it's closed under scalar multiplication. Note the subspace of such functions is the same as the space of real valued functions on a circle. This presentation might be more clearly a vector space

Comment: Your title just asks whether it is a subset, that seems quite easy.  Subspace is more difficult.  Please edit your title to be correct.

Comment: Yes it was a typo it's a subspace

Comment: The sum of two periodic functions isn't necessarily periodic if the periods are different, I don't think. Like... what if the periods are $\sqrt {2}$ and $\sqrt {3}$?

Comment: @AlfredYerger look at the OP's proof of closure under addition.

Comment: @AOrtiz The OP's proof assumes that $f$ and $g$ have the same period, and I think Alfred is pointing out that this isn't necessarily the case.

Comment: That is what I intended, yes.

Comment: @basket the period is not fixed, though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any irrational $\alpha$, the function $f(x)=\sin x+\sin(\alpha x)$ is not periodic, because $\limsup f(x)=2$ but $f(x)<2$ for every $x\in\Bbb R$.

For a proof, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1916529/is-n-mod-pi-n-in-mathbbn-dense-in-0-pi/1916576#1916576) and have in mind that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Then I need to find another function $g(x)$ such that $f(x) + g(x)$ is not periodic?

Comment: @user48029420 No, this example shows that $S$ can't possibly be a subspace, as it shows that $S$ is not closed under addition.

Comment: by showing $S$ is not closed under addition, we are assuming we have added two functions, $f_1 = sin(x)$ and $f_2 = sin(\pi x)$?

Answer (score 2):

Call $S$ the set of periodic functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. We will show that $S$ is not a vector space. During the proof, I will try to explain the motivation behind every step taken. If you are in a hurry, just go to the item **(3c)**.

In the attempt in the question, it was assumed that $f$ and $g$ have the same period $p$, which is not always the case.

As the author of the question pointed out, to check whether a set $S$ is a vector space, we must check three things: (1) $S$ it's not empty, (2) $S$ it's closed under addition and (3) $S$ is closed under scalar multiplication. Let's check these properties one by one.

**(1) $S$ is not empty**

Well, take the constant function $f(x) = 5$. Then $f(x+42) = f(x)$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$, which means $42$ is a period of $f$. Of course I could take another number to be a period --- $42$ just happens to be one I like. Could be $11$ or $13$, if you prefer. We checked that $S$ is not empty.

**(2) $S$ is closed under multiplication by a scalar**

If $f$ is periodic with period $p \in \mathbb{R}$, then by definition $f(x+p) = f(x)$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Then the function $\lambda f$ is also periodic, because $(\lambda f)(x+p) = \lambda \cdot f(x+p) = \lambda \cdot f(x) = (\lambda f)(x)$.

**(3) $S$ is closed under addition**

Let's try to prove $S$ is closed under addition. It won't work, because it's not! Take $f_1$ with period $p_1$ and $f_2$ with period $p_2$. We must show that $g = f_1 + f_2$ is also periodic.

**(a)** Sometimes $g = f_1 + f_2$ is in fact periodic. Take a look. Suppose $f_1$ has period $p_1 = 5$ and $f_2$ has period $p_2 = 7$. Then $f_1$ repeats itself on intervals of length $5$ and $f_2$ repeats itself on intervals of length $7$. Well, on intervals of length $5 \cdot 7 = 35$ both $f_1$ and $f_2$ repeats themselves. To be more precise, $(f_1+f_2)(x+35) = f_1(x+35) + f_2(x+35) = f_1(x + \mathbf{5} \cdot 7) + f_2(x + \mathbf{7} \cdot 5) = f_1(x) + f_2(x) = (f_1+f_2)(x)$.

**(b)** It appears that we can generalize that, but we can't. Take $f_1$ with period $p_1$ and $f_2$ with period $p_2$. Then $f_1$ repeats itself on every interval of length $p_1$, which means $f_1$ repeats itself on every interval of length $p_1 \cdot p_2$, right? Wrong! There is a problem: if $p_1 \cdot p_2$ is irrational, we cannot say that --- $f_1$ repeats on every interval of length $p_1$, so it repeats on every interval of a multiple of $p_1$. But a multiple of $p_1$ is $p_1$ times an integer value.

**(c, a counterexample)** Finally, let's look for a (very simple) counterexample. It get's ugly if look for your everyday functions like $sin(x)$ and $cos(x)$. Look for simpler (although artificial ones).

Take $f_1(x) = 1$ in the interval $[0,1/2]$, $f_1(x) = 1000$ in the interval $(1/2,1]$ and $f_1(x+1) = f_1(x)$. So $f_1$ has fundamental period $p_1 = 1$. Actually, the graph of $f_1$ is just two horizontal lines, $y=1$ and $y=1000$, repeating themselves.

Take $f_2(x) = 3$ in the interval $[0,1]$, $f_2(x) = 3000$ in the interval $(1,\sqrt{2}]$ and $f_2(x+\sqrt{2}) = f(x)$. So $f_2$ has fundamental period $p_2 = \sqrt{2}$. Actually, the graph of $f_2$ is just two horizontal lines, $y=3$ and $y=3000$, repeating themselves.

Suppose $g = f_1+f_2$ is periodic. Then there is a $P \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $(f_1+f_2)(x+P) = (f_1+f_2)(x)$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$. That means $f_1(x+P)+f_2(x+P) = f_1(x)+f_2(x)$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Due to the way $f_1$ and $f_2$ behave, that means $f_1(x+P) = f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x+P) = f_2(x)$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Because $p_1 = 2$ is the fundamental period of $f_1$, that means $P$ is a multiple of $p_1$. In other words, $P = k_1 p_1$ for some $k_1 \in \mathbb{N}$.

Because $p_2 = \sqrt{2}$ is the fundamental period of $f_2$, that means $P$ is a multiple of $p_2$. In other words, $P = k_2 p_2$ for some $k_2 \in \mathbb{N}$.

Well, that means $p_2 / p_1 = k_1 / k_2$, with $k_1, k_2 \in \mathbb{N}$. But $p_2 / p_1 = \sqrt{2}$. It implies that $\sqrt{2}$ is rational. So our hypothesis, that $f_1+f_2$ is periodic, is false. Therefore $f_1+f_2$ is not periodic and $S$, the set of all periodic funtions, is not a vector space.

Comment: Surely you only need to provide a counterexample?