# How to handle limit regarding integers

Tags: limits

I find it hard to prove the convergence of $\sin(n^2)$ or $\frac{\tan(n)}{n^3}$ as $n$ goes to infinity. Is there any nice way to tackle this kind of limits?

Comment: See e.g. here for discussion on $\sin\left(n^2\right)$: [$\sin(n^2)$ diverges](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2373322/sin-n2-diverges).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions such as this are related to [measures of irrationality](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrrationalityMeasure.html) of $\pi$.

If $k \pi/2$ is the closest odd multiple of $\pi/2$ to $n$, we have $|\tan(n)| \sim 1/(|n - k \pi/2|)$, so in order to have $|\tan(n)|/n^3 > \epsilon > 0$ you'll want, for some $\delta > 0$,  $|\pi - 2 n/k| < \delta/n^4$.  It's almost certainly true that there are only finitely many such pairs $(n,k)$ (and therefore that $\tan(n)/n^3 \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$), but this has not been proven.  As of 2012, the best known
bound, due to [Salikhov](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1134/S0001434610090294), is $7.606308$.  So we can say that $\tan(n)/n^{6.606308} \to 0$, but $\tan(n)/n^3$ is not yet within reach.