# About double map function $D(x) = 2x\pmod 1$ iterations

Tags: calculus, dynamical-systems

Well, I have a basic question about double map function, let's go to it...

The double map $D:[0,1) \to [0,1)$ is define by
$$
D(x) = 2x\pmod 1 = \begin{cases}
    2x       & \quad \text{if } 0 \leq x < {1\over 2}\\
    2x-1  & \quad \text{if } {1\over 2}\le x < 1
  \end{cases}$$

My doubt is that the Devaney's book "Differential Equations, Dynamics Systems, and An Introduction to Chaos" says "An easy computation shows that $D^n(x) = 2^n x \pmod 1$".

Firstilly, I was open that first equation like

\begin{align}
D(x) & \equiv 2x\pmod 1\\
1 | (2x -D(x)) &\Rightarrow k = 2x -y
\end{align}
where $y = D(x)$ and $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. So
$$
\begin{align}
&\text{If } k=0 \text{ then} \quad 2x -y=0 \Rightarrow y=2x 
\begin{cases}
    y=0  & \Rightarrow 2x=0 \Rightarrow x=0\\
    y=1  & \Rightarrow 2x=1 \Rightarrow x=1/2 
\end{cases}\\
&\text{So } 0 \leq x < 1/2.
\end{align}
$$

$$
\begin{align}
&\text{If } k=1 \text{ then} \quad 2x -y=1 \Rightarrow y=2x -1 
\begin{cases}
    y=0  & \Rightarrow 2x-1=0 \Rightarrow x=1/2\\
    y=1  & \Rightarrow 2x-1=1 \Rightarrow x=1 
\end{cases}\\
&\text{So } 1/2 \leq x < 1.
\end{align}
$$

Now, I want to proof that $D^2(x) = D(2x) = 2^2 x \pmod 1$. But I do not undestant how. What did I do

$$D(D(x)) = 2(2 x \pmod 1) \pmod 1 \Rightarrow 2(2x-y)-y=k$$

And It is not effective...

So, how can I work with the second and next $D$ iterations, to proof $D^k(x)$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$?

Thanks for help!

Comment: You can do induction over $k$. Then we have (where all the equalities are as element in $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, which is exactly what mod 1 means) $$D^{k+1}(x)= DD^k(x)= 2 D^k(x)=2^{k+1} x$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $\{x\}$ for the fractional part of $x$, and $[x]$ for the integer part of $x$, so $\{x\}=x-[x]$ and $[x]$ is an integer and $0\le\{x\}<1$. Note that $x\bmod 1$ is just another way to say $\{x\}$. You want to know why $2(2x\bmod1)\bmod1=4x\bmod1$. We'll prove that if $a,b$ are integers then $\{abx\}=\{a\{bx\}\}$. Your question is just the case $a=b=2$.

$a\{bx\}=a(bx-[bx])=abx-a[bx]\equiv abx\bmod1$, so $\{a\{bx\}\}=\{abx\}$.